General form of symmetric function of 3 dimensional vectors
In the paper Deep Sets by Zaheer et al, they prove a theorem (eq 18 in appendix) that states that any general scalar symmetric function of $M$ variables can be written as
$$f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_M) = \rho(\sum^M_{i=1} \phi(x_i))$$
where $\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{M+1}$ and $\rho : \mathbb{R}^{M+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x_1, \dots, x_M)$ is a symmetric function under exchange of $x_i$.
I'm wondering whether there exists some generalization of this to higher dimensions specifically 3 dimensions where we can say that any general scalar function of $M$ 3-vectors can be written as
$$f(\vec{r}_1, \dots, \vec{r}_M) = \rho(\sum^M_{i=1} \phi(\vec{r}_i))$$
where now $\phi : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3M+3}$ and $\rho : \mathbb{R}^{3M+3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and as before $f(\vec{r}_1, \dots, \vec{r}_M)$ is now a symmetric function under exchange of vectors. I'm wondering whether this statement is true and if anyone knows anything about this or can offer their insight that would be helpful.
